# angularjs form 'has-success' mark without entering any data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

The field **field1** is `required` in the form submission. However, when I open the form, i get a green checkmark for '`has-success`' before the label, as if the field is valid, whereas nothing has been entered in the field yet.

```
<div class="form-group"
     ng-class="{'has-error':Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.field1.$valid}">
    <label class="control-label symbol required">
        My Field
    </label>
    <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="true" ng-model="myModel.myfield1" name="field1" theme="bootstrap" title="Choose your answer" required>
        <ui-select-match placeholder="This is to be completed">
            {{$item}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="r in mydata.datafield1 | filter: $select.search">
            {{r}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.field1.$valid">This is correct!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited 2**
 I just made a plnkr for you, so you can see the behavior I get with this code:

*html*

```
<div ng-controller="foo">

<form name="Form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.field1 && Form.field1.$valid}">
    <!-- You have to check for Form.field1 property when putting the form valid as well-->
    <label class="control-label symbol required">
        My Field
    </label>
    <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="true" ng-model="myModel.myfield1" name="field1" theme="bootstrap" title="Choose your answer" required>
        <ui-select-match placeholder="This is to be completed">
            {{$item}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="r in mydata.datafield1 | filter: $select.search">
            {{r}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.field1.$valid">This is correct!</span>
  </div>
</form>

</div>
```

*controller*

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize'])
  .controller('foo', function($scope) {

  $scope.mydata = {
    datafield1: ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3']
  }

});
```

http://plnkr.co/TKj2sx

Comment: I added `Form.field1.$dirty` this to the ng class, but yeah, the success check mark is gone, but now another problem pops up, the success message is shown by default and in black. but once sth is entered , it goes green and the success mark appears, but when i clean the field, the success mark is still there!

Comment: Ok, I just edited the answer. Change `Form.field1.$dirty` for `Form.field1`

Comment: it is not working at all even with the new edit. it s the same story, showing both check mark and success message.

Comment: could you please, provide a plunker or a code snipped?, so I could help you

Comment: @Mpondomise, please, check out my answer **Edited 2** with a plunker and the code in it. The green mark is there only when correct data is in the select, otherwise if nothing is selected and the select has been touched a 'has-error' mark is shown